# When referencing an object, does it always have to be passed as a parameter

Tags: .net, parameters

I have a question about how 2 separate instances of classes can know about each.

Let's assume I have an empty console app and I've added 2 classes, in 2 separate namespaces.

Details of each class are not important, so please consider this very simple code from my Console Application Program.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Namespace1.ClassName = c = new Namespace1.ClassName();
    Namespace2.ClassName2 = c2 = new Namespace2.ClassName2();
}
```

Now, unless I pass an instance to (for example) the constructor of my ClassName2 then `c2` will have no knowledge of `c` EG

```
Namespace2.ClassName2 = c2 = new Namespace2.ClassName2(c);
```

is there any other way for `c2` to have knowledge of `c` without `c` being passed as a parameter or set as a property of `c2`.

I assume not, but I've been wrong so many times I am just after clarification. I am looking for a simple yes or no answer mainly, but any other details are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think besides the constructor argument the only way you can do it is to create a property or a setter function in `ClassName2` and than set it after you created `c2` instance

```
Namespace2.ClassName2 c2 = new Namespace2.ClassName2();
c2.SetC(c);
```

Theoretically you can also make the class `ClassName` static, but it's not a good idea

Comment: I thought this was the case but I've been wrong many times so getting the reassurance is good (I don't work with any other developers so learning is hard). Thank you, this is great

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `public static` property, so if your main method was in a `Namespace3.Program` class, for example, you could declare it as:

```
// namespace3
public class Program {
     public static Namespace1.Classname c {get;set;}

     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Pragram.c = new Namespace1.ClassName();
        Namespace2.ClassName2 c2 = new namespace2.ClassName2();
     }
}
```

Then in a ClassName2 method call

```
namespace3.Program.c
```